# How to delete a misspelled tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, editing

There are some tags like [arcgsi-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgsi-server) that were created with a spelling error. Is there a way to delete it (what actions are required then?)?

If not, how can those be flagged so moderators could delete them? I've edited the tag for the question where it was used to [arcgis-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-server).

Answer (score 7):

If no questions with that tag, it will disappear on its own in about 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

From Main Meta Stack Exchange: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags).

If a misspelled tag is perceived only when it was used in a couple of questions, then, it could be edited out like you did (but as suggested in MSE, if it is a tag used in many questions first seek some feedback from community before engaging editing). Then, it will go away as [Mapperz said](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3604/how-to-delete-a-tag/3606#3606).

Whenever you see such situation you have some options: bring the subject to meta, bring it up on chat or flag the question for 'moderator attention' and explains the situation.

There are other options on the table (not exactly related to misspellings, but avoid creation of undesired tags): like to blacklist it (avoid the tag to be created). However, this is more for undesired tags that could come up with certain frequency (for example, "gis").

Comment: Thank you, @Andre. Unfortunately, I cannot make this tag a synonym to arcgis-server; I am getting "Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag" error message.

Comment: @Alex. Yes. You need to have 5 score on the tag to only be able to suggest it to be a synonym (and minimum of 2500 rep). Other users still need to vote for your suggestion (more info, [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)). IMO, this SE feature is not very handy, and that is why I suggested you to raise the mods attention directly (they can manage tags with less restrictions). This is the fastest (and efficient) way which I've seen to resolve cases like that so far.

Comment: ok, I got it, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't that just discourage proper spelling / encourage sloppy spelling? There are some legitimate alternative spellings (color/colour, center/centre, modeling/modelling), but allowing "gsi" for "gis" seems wrong. (In that example, GSI is a total station format!)

Comment: @MartinF, re-reading my answer after a couple of years I agree with you. Making a misspelled tag a synonym is not a good idea. Hence, I edited my answer. Tks.